# What values will make this function crash?

Tags: javascript, arrays, crash, duplicates

I am thinking to use the following function:

```
function delDups(arr){
    var out=[],obj={};

    for(var i=0,len=arr.length;i<len;i++){
        obj[arr[i]]=0;
    }
    for(i in obj){
        out.push(i);
    }
    return out;
}
```

The function is slightly modified, original at be found [here](http://dreaminginjavascript.wordpress.com/2008/08/22/eliminating-duplicates/)

However, I am sure there are some values that will make it crash, and I want to know exactly what values will (so I can do soemthing about it)

Comment: also, I modified the function (I moved the `var i` inside the first loop... Do I need to put `var i` on the second loop too?

Comment: You don't need to put `var` declaration  inside the second loop. JavaScript hoists variable declarations at the top of the function, so imagine JavaScript inserting the line `var i;` at the top of your function. But that said, it is a good practice to either declare it at the top yourselves, or declare it for each for-loop just for consistency sake.

Comment: @Anurag will it create a global `i` with the code I am using?

Comment: Not a global `i`. It will be local to the entire `delDups` function.

Comment: @Anurag sorry to bother you again, but, will that mean that the second `i` is different than the first declared `var i`? (because I love to recycle vars whenever possible)

Comment: It won't be multiple variables. Even if you put multiple `var i`'s in your function, only a single variable will be created. You are just reusing that variable in each loop. If you don't prefer this recycling, then simply create a new variable for each loop - like `for (var objectKey in obj)`...

Comment: Declared variables are made properties of the current activation object. Declaring them more than once has no effect on their scope or value.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if `arr` isn't an array-like object (e.g. with a `length` and indexed properties) it will crash.

It may however also not do what you expect whenever the data in `arr` isn't an array of strings. In that case you'd get an array back with strings only, the original objects and their data type will be lost. But it will not crash...

Comment: I actually tested your theory about non arrays, and used a call delDups(6) at which point it returned an empty object.

Comment: Thanks, I will wait around 1 hour to give other ppl the chance to built a better answer. If they fail, I will accept yours

Comment: Or very large fake `length` values or very large Arrays. This actually crashed my browser. `delDups({ length: 1000000000000})`

Answer (score 1):

Crashing is not the only inconvenient outcome from executing code. Also of (perhaps greater) interest are cases where the code runs but returns an incorrect result. Your analysis might be something like:

```
for(var i=0,len=arr.length;i<len;i++){
```

In the above, it is assumed that the value of arr.length is a numeric value greater than or equal to zero. If *arr* does not have a length property, or its value isn't a non-negative number, the for loop will not behave as expected (e.g. it may result in an error or an infinite loop).

```
obj[arr[i]]=0;
```

In this line, the result of evaluating `arr[i]` is used as a property name, so wherever that expression returns something that isn't suitable as a property name, you will get an error, e.g. if `arr[i]` is an ActiveX object, you can expect unexpected outcomes. If it's a native Object the value will be the result of calling its toString method, which might provide the same value for different objects, or an error, or "just work".

```
for(i in obj){
```

will iterate over all enumerable properties of *obj*, including those it inherits. If an enumerable property is added to *Object.prototype*, it will turn up in the loop so it's common to use a *hasOwnProperty* test to filter out inherited properties.

How much you test for errors depends on the environment you expect the code to be used in. If you have reasonable control and have documented the values that are expected to be passed to the function (e.g. array of primitive values) then it is reasonable to do minimal (or no) testing of input values. If someone passes in an ActiveX object instead of an array and it goes belly up, you respond with "RTFM".

On the other hand, if it is known that the code will be used in a library in uncontrolled and widely varying situations, testing that the input has a non-negative, numeric length property seems sensible, as does adding a *hasOwnProperty* test to the for..in loop.

How much time and effort you put into making your code robust is a function of where you expect it to run, but adding some sensible and obvious checks up front may well save some grief later. So I'd do something like:

```
function delDups(arr) {
    var out=[],obj={};
    var len = arr && arr.length;

    if (len && len > 0) { 

        for(var i=0; i<len; i++) {
            obj[arr[i]] = 0;

        for (i in obj) {

            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                out.push(i);
            }
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: `var len = arr && arr.length;` what does it do?

Answer (score 0):

Woohoo! I crashed it, where is my prize?

```
var arr3 = delDups(eval());
```